# How do record the http requests on a page/url in javascript similar to the network panel from chrome?

Tags: javascript, performance, http, request

I've been trying to record the HTTP request from a URL/page similar to the way that chrome developer tools do in the network panel. time and So far I can get load time and page size. I am writing the code in javascript and from the information, I have now do you guys know any way I can record HTTP requests in javascript.
[Reference image to network panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V64F.jpg)

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<script type="text/javascript">
var start = new Date().getTime();
function onLoad() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var latency = now - start;
  alert("page loading time: " + latency+"\n"+"Start time:"+start+"\n"+"End time:"+now);
  alert("Load_size:"+document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].outerHTML.length + "KB");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
<!- Main page body goes from here. -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can measure time using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance API instead of `Date`.

Comment: Which requests you'd like to record? The ones done by the browser (loading IMG tags, CSS files, etc...) are beyond reach of regular JavaScript - you'd have to write browser plugin (or, for requests to site's domain, maybe try service worker script somehow). You could try to "catch" `AJAX` and `fetch` calls by overriding default functions.